# Howto iterate through XML by node/element names

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

Is there a way i can iterate over nodes/elements by their names like this:

```
<rootnode>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      stuff
    </bar>
 ....


document.getDocumentElement.getElement("foo").getElement("bar").getValue();
```

Comment: Do you know XPath ? Would it suit your use case ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [XPath](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) should do the trick.

Provided you already have parsed the document as `org.w3c.dom.Document`:

```
String expression = "/rootnode/foo/bar";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)   xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
}
```

Comment: Hmm xPath could be an option.. gonna try it out